# iOS 12 not received FCM notifications

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, ios12, xcode10.1

Hi I'm using **XCode version:** 10.1 (10B61) and **iPhone SE** with **iOS version:** 12.0.1 (16A404), I installed properly all configuration as documentation explained, I uploaded the Auth .p8 certificate and the p.12 certificates of development and production, but when I try to send a push notification from Firebase console I don't receive any, am I missing something? or I did some wrong? any help, please?

```
//
//  AppDelegate.swift
//  SpriteKit Game Demo
//
//  Created by Dennis Mostajo on 9/2/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 Mostys Studios.. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Fabric
import Crashlytics

import Firebase
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate
{
    var window: UIWindow?
    var navigationVC: UINavigationController?
    let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"

    override init() {
    // set Firebase configuration
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        debugPrint("didFinishLaunchingWithOptions")
        Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])
        DataBaseHelper.DBUpdate() // Run migrations

        // Enable Push Notifications
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
        debugPrint("applicationWillResignActive")
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
        debugPrint("applicationDidEnterBackground")
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
        debugPrint("applicationWillEnterForeground")
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication)
    {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
        debugPrint("applicationDidBecomeActive")
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
        debugPrint("applicationWillTerminate")
    }

    // MARK: - FIREBASE

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any])
    {
        Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey]
        {
            debugPrint("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }
        // Print full message.
        debugPrint(userInfo)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
    {
        Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey]
        {
            debugPrint("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }
        // Print full message.
        debugPrint(userInfo)
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error)
    {
        debugPrint("Unable to register for remote notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data)
    {
        debugPrint("didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: DATA")
        let token = String(format: "%@", deviceToken as CVarArg)
        debugPrint("*** deviceToken: \(token)")
        let deviceTokenString = deviceToken.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%02X", $1)})
        debugPrint("deviceTokenString: \(deviceTokenString)")
        Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
//        debugPrint("Firebase Token:",InstanceID.instanceID().token() as Any)
    }
}

// [START ios_10_message_handling]
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

        //Handle the notification ON APP
        Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(notification.request.content.userInfo)
        completionHandler([.sound,.alert,.badge])
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

        //Handle the notification ON BACKGROUND
        Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(response.notification.request.content.userInfo)
        completionHandler()
    }
}
// [END ios_10_message_handling]

extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {
    // [START refresh_token]
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")
        InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID
            {
                (result, error) in
                if let error = error
                {
                    debugPrint("Error fetching remote instange ID: \(error)")
                }
                else if let result = result
                {
                    debugPrint("Remote instance ID token: \(result.token)")
                }
            }
        let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken]
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)
        // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
        // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
    }
    // [END refresh_token]
    // [START ios_10_data_message]
    // Receive data messages on iOS 10+ directly from FCM (bypassing APNs) when the app is in the foreground.
    // To enable direct data messages, you can set Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel to true.
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
        debugPrint("Received data message: \(remoteMessage.appData)")
    }
    // [END ios_10_data_message]
}
```

Podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.0'

def shared_pods
    pod 'Fabric'
    pod 'Crashlytics'
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.7'
    pod 'RealmSwift'
    pod 'SwiftyJSON'
    pod 'PKHUD', '~> 5.0'
    pod 'Siren'
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
    pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks'
    pod 'Firebase/Crash'
end

target 'Sprite Kit Game' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  # Pods for Sprite Kit Game
    shared_pods
end

target 'Sprite Kit GameTests' do
    # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
    use_frameworks!
    # Pods for testing
    shared_pods
end

target 'Sprite Kit GameUITests' do
    # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
    use_frameworks!
    # Pods for testing
    shared_pods
end

post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            # This works around a unit test issue introduced in Xcode 10.
            # We only apply it to the Debug configuration to avoid bloating the app size
            if config.name == "Debug" && defined?(target.product_type) && target.product_type == "com.apple.product-type.framework"
                config.build_settings['ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES'] = "YES"
            end
        end
    end
end
```

no notifications are received neither by foreground nor background, any help, please?

Comment: You’re testing on a live device, correct? I remember reading somewhere it only works from a real device and has to be at least on TestFlight, but I could be wrong about the latter.

Comment: Yes, @Torewin I'm testing on a real iPhone SE, and I tried in development and release way, but I don't receive notifications in both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was resolved to update this part of the code handling the message/push notification from Firebase console

```
// [START ios_10_message_handling]
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            debugPrint("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }
        debugPrint(userInfo)
        //Handle the notification ON APP
        Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        completionHandler([.sound,.alert,.badge])
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            debugPrint("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }
        //Handle the notification ON BACKGROUND
        Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        completionHandler()
    }
}
// [END ios_10_message_handling]
```

the issue was tracked on [GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/issues/575)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you updated **iOS Deployment Target** in the NotificationService settings